# Get the unicode icon value from a custom font

Tags: css, macos, fonts, icons, glyphicons

I need to write a CSS for an icon font build using the site [flaticon](http://www.flaticon.com/). I develop using a MAC with 10.10 and can't find any way to retrieve a single character Unicode value that I need to insert inside my CSS

```
.font-icon-pencil:before {
    content: "\e038";
}
```

How can I read the contents of a font file, to get the icon codes within that custom-made font?

Comment: `font-family: font-awesome;` ?

Comment: font family is "MyFont" but it doesn't really metter, in CSS for each icon i need to make a specific class with specific character unicode value, i guess the start from 001,002, etc

Answer (score 23):

On MacOS Sierra I'm able to get a unicode value of icon in [Font Book](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201749) (default app).

1. Install the font.
2. Open the user installed font in Font Book.
3. Move the mouse on the desired icon. You should get a title saying unicode value on hover.

[image: Font Book]

Comment: Make sure you click on the grid icon in the toolbar as I found the hover didn't work initially because the first icon is selected by default.

Comment: what about for windows?

Comment: @Jonathan I have no idea sorry, the question was about MacOS.

Comment: For Windows you can use the system program 'Character Map' @Jonathan. As I recall you need to turn on a menu option in the program to see the unicode value.

Answer (score 12):

https://fontdrop.info : Very useful website where you can see all the unicode codes at once

[image]

Comment: this is the only solution that could read the ttf file i had, thanks so much

Comment: This is the thing that finally worked for me as well.

Answer (score 9):

**Edited answer (April 29th, 2015)**

*@al404it commented: "I know how to write the CSS part. I don't know how to get, from a customized font, the corresponding code to use in content: "xxxxx";"*

---

### Answer

**Option 1)**
[Font Viewer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fontviewer/), OR **s*imilar font viewer softwar*e** 
This is the easiest option.

1. Install the [FontViewer software](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fontviewer/)
2. Get the font's icon codes from the character map
3. Use any online code converter, like [Rishida Unicode Code Converter](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/), to get the escaped CSS code

If this doesn't work for you...

**Option 2)**
Use the [icomoon app](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select)

1. Sign up AND create a new project
2. In that project, import your font files (Top left button called "+ Import Icons")[image]
3. Under Fonts (Bottom right option), you'll see the list of all your icons and respective codes.

This should work for sure.

---

### Original answer

```
@font-face {
    font-family: icons;
    src: url(MyFont.ttf); /* Replace with thatever your font file is */
}
.font-icon-pencil:before {
    font-family: icons, sans-serif;;
    content: "\e038";
}
```

Comment: i know hot to write the CSS part i don't know how to get, from a customized font, the corresponding code to use in  content: "xxxxx";

Comment: @al404IT While I look for an answer to your question, I would suggest to edit your question and start a bounty. This is due to your question not being clear as to what you really want (to get the "CSS content" codes from the font files)

Comment: with font viewer i can't see any info about character under character map, with second method i can import my font that is a .ttf file it says "Please choose SVG images, SVG fonts or JSONs exported by IcoMoon."