# Loading icons as a font-family

Tags: css, icons, font-face

I have just added a custom .ttf to my web application.

```
@font-face{
  font-family: 'CustomIcons';
  src: font-url('CustomIcons.ttf') format("truetype");
}
```

I don't care about browser compatibility yet.

Now that the icons are loaded, I don't know how can I use them. I don't have a css like when adding the FontAwesome icons, so I am not sure about how the mapping is.

Do you know how can I do to know that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the bane of existence for undocumented Icon Fonts.

If you're looking to see what is mapped to what, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29836809/393219) from @Omar has a great run down of how to reverse-engineer the weird character mappings.

> Option 2) Use the [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select) app
>
> Sign up AND create a new project In that project, import your font
>   files (Top left button called "+ Import Icons") Under Fonts (Bottom
>   right option), you'll see the list of all your icons and respective
>   codes. This should work for sure.