# How to find char codes of all characters in a file

Tags: javascript, fonts, p5.js

I am trying to get all the character codes in a .ttf/.otf file so I can get a random character and display it. I want to create a matrix rain, I found a font file with only the characters used in it only.[Here is the link to the font](https://www.dafont.com/matrix-code-nfi.font). I am trying to implement it this way: `String.toCharCode();`

My code so far:

```js
var value = String.fromCharCode(97);
var fontSize = 30;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500,500);
  textFont('Matrix');
  textSize(fontSize);
}

function draw() {
  ellipse(width/2,height/2,9,9);
  text(value,width/2,height/2);
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
 <style type = "text/css">
 @font-face {
 font-family: "Matrix";
 src: url(--Link to file--);
 }
</style>
```

research:

[How to set font size and font style](https://p5js.org/examples/typography-words.html)

[Set custom font to use in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247145/get-the-unicode-icon-value-from-a-custom-font)

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Getting the character codes present in a font will not get you where you want. The font file you linked to has other code points as well - latin letters and a maker's logo. You need to manually pick the character codes you want.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I have tried using the U+xxxx method but it leaves the square that means the character is unidentifiable. I also tried converting that number into hex, which also didn't work.

Comment: @SamiHult but how do I pick out those character points, I tried using a font viewer, but it doesn't show the code. The maker's logo is not a worry as I can iterate past it.

Comment: First of all, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602020/how-to-create-a-string-or-char-from-an-ascii-value-in-javascript
Then check again the page linked by you, which clearly enumerates the character codes next to the font glyphs.

Comment: @SamiHult I tried what you said, it works well but the fonts are overwritten, there is an 'a' under the intended text(ASCII number used is 'a' char code).

Comment: You need to render the text using the given font.

Comment: @SamiHult I have (using `loadFont(name);`), I set the family name and source in a CSS snippet in html as an error occurred. The text appears, but the default font appears beneath it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you have come up with so far, your research and especially *code*.

Comment: @SamiHult done, I think I missed some research links as I don't remember what I have used and my history log is too big.

Comment: I suggest you try to follow with more precision the code example in the [first link you provided](https://p5js.org/examples/typography-words.html) and, if you get stuck again, place a new question. Follow the [guidelines for writing a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this offline, don't do this in the browser. The font is going to be the same each time round, so its supported character mappings will be, too.

Run the font through [TTX](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools), then get the `<cmap>` table data, which is the only authority when it comes to which charcodes/code points are supported by a font. It might support multiple charsets: you only care about subtable format 4 (and possibly 12), for platform/id/encoding combination 3/1/0 (which is the platform-agnostic Unicode encoding. It's the only one we care about in 2018)

Then do with that whatever you want, but given JS context you probably want to further massage it to create a sensible JSON format so you can just load that directly using JSON.parse on the javascript side.